# how to parse that json object on android anyone help please?

Tags: json

[{
    "Category": "Addresses",
    "AddressDetail": [{
        "Title": "Dunya Ticaret Merkezi",
        "Phone":"747",
        "Latitude": "39.903712",
        "Longitude": "32.865229"
    }, {
        "Title": "Tepe Prime",
        "Phone":"737",
        "Latitude": "39.910020",
        "Longitude": "32.755583"
    }]
}]

Answer (score 0):

my code is sth. like this, how to change correct form?

String strJson="{ [{\"Category\": \"Addresses\",\"AddressDetail\": [{\"Title\": \"Dunya Ticaret Merkezi\","
                + "\"Phone\":\"747\", \"Latitude\": \"39.903712\",\"Longitude\": \"32.865229\"}, "
                + "{\"Title\":\"Tepe Prime\",\"Phone\":\"737\",\"Latitude\": \"39.910020\",\"Longitude\":\"32.755583\"}]}]}";

```
           String data = "";


           try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(strJson);


                JSONArray jarRow = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Category");
                for(int i=0;i<jarRow.length(); i++){
                    // creating an object first
                    JSONObject ElementsObj = jarRow.getJSONObject(i);
                    // and getting the array out of the object
                    JSONArray jarElements = ElementsObj.getJSONArray("AddressDetail");
                    for(int j=0; j<jarElements.length(); j++){
                        JSONObject distanceObj = jarElements.getJSONObject(j).getJSONObject("distance");
                        String distanceStr = distanceObj.getString("Title");
                        int Phone = distanceObj.getInt("Phone");
                        Log.v("finally getting distance : ", distanceStr);
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```